# Extracting data before specific character

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have number of data which has dates and time in a cell sometime there are multiple dates and time value in the cell sometimes 1, 2, or more.

So i have been trying to extract the dates and my formula is working fine but does not extract the other dates except single/first available in the cell.

```
=LEFT(A2,(FIND("-",A2,1)-1))
```

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Google Sheets:***

In `C2` try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A," .*",""))
```

[image]

---

***Excel Microsoft365:***

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,LEFT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),10))
```

Drag down...

[image]

---

Btw, decide which route you are taking, Excel or Google-Sheets. Whilst they may appear to be very similar, they are really not.

Comment: Thank you @JvdV but still the formula is not extracting dates more than one which is first.

Comment: I agree with what you stated about `Excel or Google-Sheets` but i need solution in both that's why posted this.

Comment: @Mento, see screenshots, it works fine for me. And about a solution for both. As I stated they are quite different. As per this example, `FILTERXML()` is not available in GS and `REGEXREPLACE()` is not available in Excel. You should really try to focus on just a single application here.

Comment: I respect your answer and removed the Excel based solution. I have uploaded a picture in my question with the google Sheets formula where its not working

Comment: Can you share your Sheet@Mento?

Comment: [Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wdpu7vPl3LwqqzK7Zs5XwPoVrviqMtafdSdt0E0mnCg/edit?usp=sharing) Sure.

Comment: @Mento, the problem was that your data was not seperated by newline characters, just comma-seperated. It just appeared as such on your screenshot. Therefor you can try: `=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A," -.*?\)",""))`

Comment: Thank you very very much for the help @JvdV

Answer (score 0):

I tested an alternative and hope to be able to contribute.

```
=LEFT(A2,(FIND(" - ",A2,1)))
```